# Which IDE for C++ Development on Windows 8?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, visual-studio, ide

I have a problem Dev-C++ and CodeBlocks on Windows 8. Actually, I have a problem g++. So, which IDE for C++ Development on Windows 8 should I use? (64 bit)

Comment: This is very subjective.

Comment: Maybe you could explain _what_ problem you have? Otherwise, [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) is "free as in beer".

Comment: It's true.But I should be faster,I want to fast,easy and light C++ IDE (compiler).

Comment: Notepad, command line, makefiles and GCC? Much lighter than that is hard to find.

Comment: It's lighter but it isn't faster.I guess,I will use Visual Studio Express.

Comment: @drceng If you're a student at university you may even be able to get Visual Studio 2012 for free if your university can give you Microsoft Dreamspark access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx) is the best IDE to use for C++.

Comment: And it runs on Linux, MacOS X?

Comment: "best" is very subjective, independent of the proposal

Comment: But everything can be developed on windows. It's like infinities and bigger infinities. You don't know which problems the poster has to solve on windows. Does he need a quick way to write code-snippets? Device-Drivers? Qt Applications? Your answer says: Come to MSVC, it is The One Best, including gtk-Development, MFC-development, Android-Development, and all you can think of. ..... This is why "the best" is way too broad, especially to answer such a way too broad question.

Comment: All right, we've had our fun. Let's not start flamewars in the comments, and keep things focused on the technical merits of questions and answers.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

Or a lighter Version of it: [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/).

For MFC Programming use [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/).

Note that MFC is Windows only, so if you want to develop full compatible applications: don't use it, instead use GTK.

Comment: I agree with that. There is always a big discussion for/against Eclipse/Visual Studio. I for myself rely on Eclipse CDT with Makefile projects or the vim/Makefile/gdb/valgrind command line "IDE". On Windows you might as well use Visual Studio. If you want to develop cross-platform software you should probably have a look at g++/glibc that is cross-platform. If you use Windows libraries you're certainly stuck with Windows.

Comment: Netbeans is nice, but it's not lighter version of Eclipse.

Comment: As of version 7.2.1 NetBeans does not officially support Windows 8 yet, although it should run fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write win 8 applications that are going to be distributed with Windows Store (namely WinRT applications), you can do it only with Visual Studio.
And if you want to write regular old style native applications, you can use any IDE of your choice, CodeBlocks, Eclipse, Visual Studio or anything else you like.

Edit: To be sincere, considering my not so big development experience (3 yrs), Visual Studio is the most stable, reliable and flexible IDE under Windows. But it comes with a cost, which is, it's not open source like Eclipse and the likes, and you will need to buy a license to use it for commercial purposes (for non Express versions).

Comment: There's no special license you need to buy for commercial purposes.  You can either pay for the non-express version, which has no restrictions on what you use if for.  Or you get  the Express version, which also has no restrictions on what you use it for, it just has less functionality.